# Return Bootstrap column width with SASS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get a title in a column to overlap the next column without using position:absolute and preferably keeping the width of the title as wide as col-8 column to keep in proportions for smaller screens. Is there a way to achieve this using Bootstrap variables or mixins with SASS?

[Here is an example of the desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9noXw.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, in general, not possible since the main idea of a grid is to contain content inside columns.

Now you can achieve a similar effect (moving out the columns) when you combine CSS `transform` scale with lower `font-size`.
You can take it further and add the `col-8` media queries as well.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale